# SQL Lite Database not being Created Pycharm using SQL Flask Alchemy and version 3.4

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I've searched for this answer for the past day and a half and I think my issue has something to do with my Pycharm Settings.  When I run the code below I don't get any errors but the database file never gets created.  I'm trying to recreate the app following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2geC50roans

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE__URI'] = 'sqlite:///pin.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Pin(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)`enter code here`
    title = db.Column(db.Text, unique=False)
    image = db.Column(db.Text, unique=False)


db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


app.debug = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

    enter code here
```

Comment: Does it create the database when run outside of PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

This code does not create the database as mentioned in the link you provided:
*To create the initial database, just import the db object from an interactive Python shell and run the SQLAlchemy.create_all() method to create the tables and database:...*

To create the db programatically, use create_engine:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mydirectory/myfile.db, convert_unicode=True)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
Base.query = session.query_property()
```

More info:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlalchemy/